# Дана матрица. Выяснить является ли сумма четных элементов положительным числом

Tags: python

Данный код генерирует одномерный массив. Как переделать его по заданию?

```
from random import random
N = 10
arr = [0] * N
for i in range(N):
   arr[i] = int(random() * 10) - 5
print(arr)
s = 0
for i in range(N):
  if arr[i]%2 == 0:
    s += arr[i]
if s >= 0:
    print(s)
else:
    print('Error')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

мб так

```py
from random import random

n, m, arr = int(input()), int(input()), []
for i in range(n):
    arr.append([])
    for j in range(m):
        arr[i].append(int(random() * 10) - 5)

summ = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        summ += arr[i][j] if arr[i][j] % 2 == 0 else 0
    print(arr[i])

print(summ > 0)
```